# Migrating iMessages to new MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages

I'm trying to migrate my old messages from my old MacBook Pro to a new one I just bought.

I tried copying over the old Messages folder, including `chat.db`, `chat.db-shm`, and `chat.db-wal`.

I then restarted my Mac and it has created new `chat.db`, `chat.db-shm`, and `chat.db-wal` files - and it appears to have renamed the files I copied over from my old Mac as `chat.db.incompatible.v11026.sqlite.db`, `chat.db.incompatible.v11026.sqlite.db-shm`, and `chat.db.incompatible.v11026.sqlite.db-wal`.

I've done this multiple times and the same thing keeps happening. Any advice would be appreciated!